# cron job not running from cron.daily

Tags: cron

I have added a job (`register-dns.cron`) to `/etc/cron.daily/`, but it is not running. The result of some testing is shown below.

```
#↳ ls -l /etc/cron.daily/
total 28
-rwxr-xr-x 18 root root 1474 Sep 13  2017 apt-compat
-rwxr-xr-x 13 root root  355 Oct 25  2016 bsdmainutils
-rwxr-xr-x 18 root root 1597 Feb 22  2017 dpkg
-rwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4125 Feb 10 08:26 exim4-base
-rwxr-xr-x 18 root root  249 May 17  2017 passwd
-rwxr-xr-x  3 root root   66 Apr 17 11:57 register-dns.cron

#↳ (cd /; run-parts --report --verbose /etc/cron.daily)

run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/apt-compat
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/exim4-base
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/passwd

#↳ (cd /; run-parts --report --verbose --reverse /etc/cron.daily)
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/passwd
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/exim4-base
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/dpkg
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
run-parts: executing /etc/cron.daily/apt-compat
```

Comment: Have you try to remove `.cron`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes I did, see my answer bellow. But thanks any ways.

Comment: Not off topic. the answer is useful. Knowing that `run-parts` has some arbitrary rule to only allow some characters in filename, is useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems that by removing the `.cron` from the end of the filename, it will start to work. (dots are not allowed in filename, see below ).

From `man run-parts`

> If  neither  the  --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.