# Getting cron to work on docker

Tags: cron, docker

I am using `nginx` in docker. I have configured `cron` jobs to update SSL certificates and DNS registration. However the `cron` jobs are not running.

What have I done. I have created a `Dockerfile` based on `arm32v7/nginx` this intern is based on `debian:stretch-slim`. At first I installed `cron`, and assumed that it would run, but then discovered that the service was not started (there is no init subsystem installed, debian:stretch-slim is very minimal). So I added code to start `cron`. Now if I ask the container if `cron` is running it says yes.

```
#ctrl-alt-delor@raspberrypi:~/a_website/docker$
#↳ docker exec -it $(docker container ls | sed -nr -e 's/.*(website-stack.*)/\1/p') service cron status
[ ok ] cron is running.
```

However I am not seeing any logs from the task that I have added to `cron`.

If I run `run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily`, the my tasks get run, and produce log output. Therefore it still appears as if `cron` is not running.

```
#ctrl-alt-delor@raspberrypi:~/a_website/docker$
#↳ docker exec -it $(docker container ls | sed -nr -e 's/.*(website-stack.*)/\1/p') cat /proc/12/cmdline; echo
/usr/sbin/cron
```

**So why is `cron` not running its jobs?** What have I missed?

## `Dockerfile`

```
FROM arm32v7/nginx

##add backports
COPY stretch-backports-source.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

##install cron and curl — so we can register dns regularly
RUN     apt-get update &&\
        apt-get install -y cron curl &&\
        apt-get clean

##setup cron to register dns
COPY register-dns register-dns.auth register-dns-hostname /usr/local/bin/
COPY register-dns.cron /etc/cron.daily/1-register-dns
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/register-dns /etc/cron.daily/1-register-dns

##add curtbot
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -t stretch-backports install -y python-certbot-nginx && \
    apt-get clean


#add ssl port
EXPOSE 443 80

##custom entry point — needed by cron
COPY entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"] #:tricky: we seem to need to re-specify this

LABEL name="my-nginx" \
      description="nginx + cron + curl + certbot + dns-registering"
```

## `entrypoint`

```
#!/bin/sh

## Do whatever you need with env vars here ...
service cron start

# Hand off to the CMD
exec "$@"
```

## `/etc/crontab`

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

## `/etc/cron.daily/1-register-dns`

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> /var/log/register-dns
/usr/local/bin/register-dns >>/var/log/register-dns
```

Comment: Have you created `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`  inside the container?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no (however the directory exists). Tell me more.

Comment: I have as `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.daily/1-reginter-dns`. They are listed in question. The `/etc/crontab` it the one that came with the instillation (it is not edited). It looks like it says once per day do `cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily`. But it is not doing it. If I type that into the shell, it does it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I installed `rsyslog` to see what errors I was getting I got the following

`(*system*) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/crontab)`. A bit of searching told me that `cron` has a security policy to not work if there are lots of hard-links to its files. Unfortunately Docker's layered file-system makes files have lots of hard-links.

To fix it, I added `touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*`, to the start up script, before running `cron`. This dis-attaches if from the other file-instances.

The new entrypoint is

```
#!/bin/sh

#fix link-count, as cron is being a pain, and docker is making hardlink count >0 (very high)
touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*

service cron start

# Hand off to the CMD
exec "$@"
```

I have tested and it works

## Summary

To get `cron` to work you will have to.

- Install `cron` — if not installed
- Add cron job to `/etc/cron.daily/` (or weekly). Ensure that your script-name, has only letters, numbers, hyphens, **no dots**. (Don't ask) see [cron job not running from cron.daily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438473/cron-job-not-running-from-cron-daily)
- Get the hardlink count of `cron`s config files down to one: do `touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*` — (if in docker). I put it in the start-up script.
- Start `cron`: `service cron start` — (If on a basic OS, with no init. As in a lot of base images for use in docker). I put it in the starts-up script.

The entrypoint script from this answer, and everything else from the question, will do it. Current project can be fetched with `hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/davids_dad/a_website`

Comment: Would you explain how touching it makes the difference? It got me curious.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think it is because it makes it a different instance of the file, in the layered file-system, that docker uses.

Comment: Makes sense, will have to remember investigating it. thanks.